# How does apt handle circular dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

When I installing `.deb` packages by hand I often encounter circular dependencies.

I, then, install it with `dpkg -i --force-depends ...` and hope it works.

How does `apt` handle circular dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependencies happen in [the repositories](http://debian.semistable.com/debgraph.out.html), but the ones left standing obey some specific rules.

Usually these are tightly bound packages (such as between [`g++-4.6`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/g++-4.6) and [`libstdc++6-4.6-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libstdc++6-4.6-dev), or `perl` and `perl-modules`), so the `Depends` relationship between them specify the exact version number. For example, `g++-4.6 4.6.3-1ubuntu5` depends on `libstdc++6-4.6-dev (= 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`, and `libstdc++6-4.6-dev 4.6.3-1ubuntu5` on `g++-4.6 (= 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`. Such packages are always installed, upgraded or removed together. As to the algorithm that `apt-get` uses, I don't know, but you can read up on the `aptitude` algorithm on the [`aptitude` creator's page](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/blog/entry/from-blogspot/2005-05-09--21:30:00/).

Comment: That's an interesting link. Thanks for sharing. It does not account for all I have found so far, though. Weird.

Comment: @muru you mean apt really does not mean the last package as of linear depends on the package which depends on it? But instead apt try to express that the last dep is a sole dependency only by the other mentioned